# Setting SDK version fallback resource values in UWP

Tags: xaml, sdk, uwp, resources, fallback

My application is compiling against **Windows Creators Update (15063)**, but is supposed to run on a minimum version of **10586**; however, some colour resources we used seem to be missing on old versions.
The exact whereabouts of failing resources are unknown (as the incompatible resources are), so temporarily, I want to give a global fallback value to eliminate crashes on old SDKs.
Is there any programmatic `C#` or automatic `XAML` way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether certain features are available at runtime. There are many ways how to achieve that. You can read more about how to write version adaptive code for example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-code) and [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/#A7P6pGd1R2kc5mf2.97).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not yet a solution to my problem, I'm looking for a way to set a global callback for color resources.